# $P=(m,n)$, $Q=(h,j)$. Prove that $P\subseteq Q$ iff $h\leq m\leq n\leq j$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$P=(m,n)$, $Q=(h,j)$. Prove that $P⊆Q$ iff $h≤m≤n≤j$

I have no idea about how to prove it, does anyone could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P\subseteq Q$. Since $P$ is presumable a non degenerate interval, we know that $m\le n$. But given $P\subseteq Q$, what can we say about the relationship between $h$ and $m$ and between $n$ and $j$.

Going the other way, simply draw a number line and label you points appropriately, then you should see how to proceed.